# How do I hide a button when printing?

Tags: vb.net, forms, printing, printform

After searching for a solution on the internet, I found this on CodeProject from 2007:

```
VisibleWhilePrinting = false
```

This does not seem to exist in VB.Net. Is there something out there that I can use to hide a button when printing a form? (other than manually setting the button's "visible" property to hidden every time the form is printed).

Thanks.

Comment: Very weird request (whose exact utility is not too clear either). Additionally, no code/reference is given.

Comment: According to the comments on that CodeProject page, the above property only exists in the commercial version of PrintForm from TMG, and is an older version of the PowerPack tools.  Read a little of that paee and you can see that other people were having the same problem as you.

Comment: user2721815, (well... future readers, because you don't say too much) for next time you want to ask about something which has less than 5 occurrences in the whole web: at least, make sure that the references are reliable enough (for example, now "VisibleWhilePrinting" has 2 more occurrences thanks to this post). For .NET, Microsoft (via MSDN) is the most solid reference. If something is not referred by Microsoft, well... Someone might have mistyped the name (and other forums repeated this mistake, like this one, this time) or any other thing.

Comment: @varocarbas, if you had bothered to read the question rather than just criticizing it, you would have seen that I clearly said the command in question "did not seem to exist in VB.Net". So obviously, I'm looking for something ELSE that does. That was the question. Is there something BESIDES the stated command that will do the same job. Yet you proceed to post no less than four more comments all addressing the non-extant command and how "weird" it is to make such a request. I found my answer, no thanks to users like you, so flame on.

Comment: "if you had bothered to read the question"? "criticizing it"? -> what are you talking about. I always read the questions (and understand what the other person says before answering anything; what you are not doing right now). The whole point of my comments since the start was: THIS IS NOT THE PLACE FOR SUCH A QUESTION. Firstly because it implies that you might not have the minimum knowledge; secondly because its whole point (an in-built flag telling you when something is being printed?! Why don't you create it?!) is none.

Comment: " I found my answer" -> where? what was the answer? That you were asking something pointless?.  "thanks to users like you" (referring to me)? -> Can you please take a look at my profile and at yours? What has been your exact contribution to SO ever? You are only asking (questions in the range of -1 to 1), never mark an answer (everyone is here for you, aren't they?)... and contribute towards wasting my time and others', decreasing the reliability of SO by asking things with no point. If you wouldn't be asking such a thing, I wouldn't have to correct you, to vote to close this answer, etc.

Comment: @varocarbas, I read your bio. Now I see where the poor attitude comes from. For someone who says "I get a bit sad because of you seriously thinking that your test can assess my knowledge". You must have a lot of self esteem issues. You are just too smart for all of us idiots here on SO. So don't waste your time answering questions for people like me. Just go on with your life thinking you are superior to everyone else. So if you want to know how I found my answer, well your so smart, you figure it out. As for that job you are looking for, no one is going to hire you with an attitude like that.

Comment: OK to everything... but just one short question: where have you got "I get a bit sad because of you seriously thinking that your test can assess my knowledge" exactly from?... It sounds as a (serious) misinterpretation of a bit old version of my profile (I am updating it regularly; just go there to see the last version)... What I meant by then was that I felt a bit sad about people giving more importance to SO points than what they really have (-> by referring to those who up-vote friends and down-vote foes; not to correctness)

Comment: Could you please provide me (and future readers) with a link where my words are written (not your wrong interpretation?). In any case, I don't know what to say... keeping track of my profile for so long? (this was deleted over 2-3 months ago)... Thanks: I am honoured.

Comment: I shouldn't even bother wasting my time with this, but just to prove my point, it took two clicks; your profile, then you website link at the top of your profile. About half way down the page the exact quote is there (not my interpretation). http://es.gravatar.com/varocarbas (you better change it quickly before "future readers" get a chance to see it). It was not deleted 2-3 months ago. I just read it for the first time yesterday. I've never heard of you before. This will be my last comment on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a method that handle's this type of behaviour? The code you provided is probably a variable that is referenced somewhere in the code to determine what needs to take place, for ex:

```
 Dim VisibleWhilePrinting As Boolean = False
```

Then this can be used or set anywhere and then used where you need it to. In order to hide a button just depends on why you need to hide it. As you have already stated about the `visible` property of the button itself. So as I have said, create a method and call it or a function...

UPDATE

As @varocarbas has mentioned, there isn't a automatic way of acheiving this, only manually.

Comment: Your answer does not address the problem (the OP is asking for an in-built flag which accounts for everything automatically; actually, not doing it manually is expressely stated; and your proposal would do it "manually") and might contribute to extend this "idea" further. Right answer: there is not such a thing. Question for the OP (out of curiosity): please provide a link to this code because I haven't been able to find any reference to this variable in the web.

Comment: @varocarbas Good catch, thanks mate! I guess I sould have said that there isn't a way to do it automatically; I didn't.

Comment: Your are welcome. I wasn't sure about the exact point of this answer, but now everything is clear to me.

Comment: @varocarbas.  I found the link by searching for "VisibleWhilePrinting PrintForm".  It looks like this is severely outdated though.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19413/All-about-PrintForm-component-1-0

Comment: @APrough Good one. Actually it appears also when typing "VisibleWhilePrinting" (what I typed) but it is the last result and there is only one occurrence, so I missed it... In any case, it is just a veriable of a program; if you cannot differentiate between a variable and a .NET property, you should better learn a bit instead of asking here. This is a completely off-topic question.

Comment: @APrough PS: I read your comment above. Are you saying that "VisibleWhilePrinting" is (was) a .NET property (even inside PowerPacks)?! Why is there no MSDN information at all?

Comment: @varocarbas.  That is what it looks like, but I have no idea why any documentation would not be available.  I haven't downloaded the old PowerPack (nor will I; why go backwards), so I agree this is off-topic.

Comment: @APrough Sure, no doubt on the off-topic front. But just to clarify this issue: it sounds a bit too weird to me. There are only 6 references (2 of them from this post) and none of them is even remotely linked to Microsoft or any other trustworthy enough source. I have seen this in the past many times: someone writes something (mistypes the name of a property, for example) and other forums repeat the mistake. This code is from 2007! PowerPacks are a bit "marginal", but even though... in less than 7 years a full removal! Not even people asking/complaining/commenting. This is too weird.

Comment: There is mention on the CodeProject site that this may belong to a 3rd-party commercial add-in.  Not enough info to elaborate more, though.